# Read write XML node values in "NodeJs"

Tags: node.js, readxml

Can anyone guide me with how to read/ write XML nodevalues parsed by xml2js.Parser() in 'NodeJS'? So far my code is as flows:

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile( './foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
    });
});
```

I want to read the values of `result` as follows

```
result.to
```

my XML:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you have to check the value of  result.note.to[0] :

```
xml2js = require('xml2js');
fs = require('fs');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile( './foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result.note.to[0]);
    });
});
```